# Documentation for ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, yaml

Where can one find full documentation for the Python package [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) which loads and dumps YAML files? The Python Package Index only gives a example of how to use comments. I am trying to understand how to use the package overall.

Answer (score 0):

The package (largely) functions as [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation), so examples for that package for general usage apply.

The specifics for round-tripping and accessing round-trip information like comments are under-documented, partly because of apparent laziness of the package author, partly because this is not intended (yet) as a standardised way of retrieving/manipulating the information.

The documentation for ruamel.yaml is now on [readthedocs](http://yaml.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) (but this is currently what you already used to find at PyPi). For specifics of the new functionality of ruamel.yaml (over PyYAML) the [tests](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/1cbc6a8dc5ca1ccbb0bb4da9def84ab0b33a4582/_test/?at=default) are very informative as well.

---

<sub>If you have any questions and tag them [pyyaml](/questions/tagged/pyyaml), the author will be notified (just using [yaml](/questions/tagged/yaml), doesn't get him an email.</sub>